# html how to make "input" text is different from value passing to server

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone please tell me whether there is a way to differentiate the text showing on the input button and the value it will pass into server when click the button.

For example, I have a input button, when it is clicked, I would like it to pass "100" into server (I just set value = 100), but instead of showing me "100" on the button, I would like it to show "200".

In this case, is there a way to do it ? what if I don't use "button" instead?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, one way would be to use a hidden field instead of relying on the button's value:

```
<!-- Instead of -->
<form>
     <input type="submit" name="buttonName" value="200">
</form>   
<!-- Do this -->
<form>
     <input type="hidden" name="buttonName" value="100">
     <input type="submit" value="200">
</form>
```

Or you can use a `button` instead of `input`, and it can have a different text and value:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" name="buttonName" value="100">200</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there anyother way I can user some attribute in input element to show the text?

Comment: See my edit - a `button` can have different text and values, and by default looks the same as an `input` button.

Comment: Thanks Joe, i will try this one.

Comment: An interesting solution with the button, but unfortunately it does not work in Internet Explorer.